# Omega 4 add region to layout

Tags: theming

I've found info to add regions to a custom layout in an Omega 4 subtheme. 
Regions need to be declared in theme.info, layout.inc and then printed/rendered in layout.tpl.php.

I've done all that and they don't appear on the page after cache clearing.

Note:

- They do appear in /admin/structure/block (I can add blocks to the
  regions there but they aren't displayed on the actual pages).
- The regions also appear if I edit the theme.info file, and
  templates/system/page.tpl.php file, and disable the use of layouts in
  omega 4 subtheme settings.

Code i used in following files:
/theme.info

```
regions[footercolumnone] = Footer Column one
regions[footercolumntwo] = Footer Column two
regions[footercolumnthree] = Footer Column three
regions[footercolumnfour] = Footer Column four
```

/layouts/owr/owr-layout.tpl.php

```
<div class="l-footer-column1"><?php print render($page['footercolumnone']); ?></div>
<div class="l-footer-column2"><?php print render($page['footercolumntwo']); ?></div>
<div class="l-footer-column3"><?php print render($page['footercolumnthree']); ?></div>
<div class="l-footer-column4"><?php print render($page['footercolumnfour']); ?></div>
```

/layouts/owr/owr.layout.inc

```
regions[footercolumnone] = Footer Column one
regions[footercolumntwo] = Footer Column two
regions[footercolumnthree] = Footer Column three
regions[footercolumnfour] = Footer Column four
```

Comment: I found that my /layouts/owr/owr.layout.inc file still said:

    template = simple-layout

instead of

    template = owr-layout

Changing it to the latter fixed my issue. Don't know why/where that parameter is used though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my /layouts/owr/owr.layout.inc file still said: template = simple-layout instead of template = owr-layout Changing it to the latter fixed my issue. Don't know why/where that parameter is used though.